# Troubles with "Upgrade Integration Components" in Windows Virtual PC (Windows 7)

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-virtual-pc

When I choose Tools / Upgrade Integration Components, the installation goes through, but it complains that the following processes are running:

- Virtual machine User Service
- Windows Explorer

If I say Ignore, I get the error message:

Setup was interrupted before Virtual PC Integration Components could be completely Installed.

Do you know how to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution worked for me:

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en/w7itprovirt/thread/96d3164e-1a86-4e63-854e-f227e037b645

Except, that I had to reboot my guest machine twice.